# advantage of converting to Base 64 encoding?

Tags: java, encoding, base64

UTF-8 are methods to encode Unicode strings to byte sequences.
Base64 is a method to encode a byte sequence to a string

Here is the example how we convert the string to bytes first and then base64 string

```
String base64encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("TestString".getBytes("utf-8"));
```

Now i send the base 64 data over network . My question is as data is always travelled as byte sequence then what's the advantage of converting back
byte sequence to string ? I know i am missing some  point here but don't know what's that ?

Comment: base64 always converts to ASCII which can be thought of as bytes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You generally convert to base64 when you are passing binary data (which could be any byte value from 0 to 255) over a text protocol. e.g. in JSON, XML, Email.

Comment: Thanks Peter. But that's what myquestion is as data is always travelled as byte sequence then what's the advantage of converting back byte sequence to string through base 64 ?

Comment: @emilly sometimes protocols are built on top of bytes which assume the data is in text not binary. e.g. they use `PrintWriter` and `BufferedReader` which expects text meaning that `\r` and `\n` are given special meanings and if you have this in your binary this will cause a problem unless the data is encoded.

Comment: But I don't see people using base 64 while uploading attachment/images over http ? Second question even after conversion to base64 string, data will travel in bits but in packets of 6bits at a time. Right ?

Comment: @emilly HTTP supports sending binary data. In base64, every 4 encoded bytes contains 3 original bytes. You can't pass just 6 bits usually.